# How to reliably change navbar breakpoint (without breaking anything else) in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

How can one easily alter the collapse breakpoint on bootstrap v3's navbar?

The documentation says

> Changing the collapsed mobile navbar breakpoint The navbar collapses
>   into its vertical mobile view when the viewport is narrower than
>   @grid-float-breakpoint, and expands into its horizontal non-mobile
>   view when the viewport is at least @grid-float-breakpoint in width.
>   Adjust this variable in the Less source to control when the navbar
>   collapses/expands. The default value is 768px (the smallest "small" or
>   "tablet" screen).

But there is no LESS file that I can see and I really want to create a custom file to override this behaviour rather than mess around with the source files.

Specifically within the Bootstrap gem file structure, I am looking for the @grid-float-breakpoint variable.

Comment: *I really want to create a custom file to override this behaviour rather than mess around with the source files.* Yes, create a `custom.css` file and override with new styles.

Comment: Thanks - now if you read the question I am looking for help on where the key variable is within the file structure of the Rails bootstrap gem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling from source (LESS files). Just open variables.less and search for the @grid-float-breakpoint.

Its default value should be @screen-sm-min, you're free to change this to any value compatible - a variable or a static value.